# How to debug low resources with Firebird SQL server?

Tags: debugging, out-of-memory, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm getting following error messages:

```
XNET: can't start worker thread, connection terminated

Operating system call _beginthreadex failed. Error code 8
```

Which according to [bug tracker](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3495) means that Firebird server process is running out of memory.

How I can debug which client is causing this problem?

I'm running Firebird 2.5.2 SuperServer.

Comment: You can look at the various `MON$...` tables (eg `MON$MEMORY_USAGE`), but in general you should check if you are properly closing or reusing resources (like connections, statements etc).

Comment: There are 3rd party applications accessing the database, so it's not possible to check every application. Also accessing those MON$... tables could be hard if FB is stuck.

Comment: You could use the system trace facility, but that might impact performance as well.

Comment: you probably got this error when db buckup start?